# Modal JInternalFrames - GlassPane disappears after resizing

Tags: java, swing

First, I make GlassPane visible, then I add JInternalFrame to it. The GlassPane successfully blocks access to GUI elements under it HOWEVER when I try to resize JInternalFrame the GlassPane disappears and I have no idea why.

The internal frame sits still on it. It looks like something changes setVisible method of the Glasspane to false... How to fix it?

Here is some code. When I resize JInternalFrame the glassPane goes missing.

```
import java.awt.Cursor;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.beans.PropertyVetoException;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;

public class Example {

    private static JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    private static JDesktopPane glassPane = new JDesktopPane();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // make JDesktopPane (glassPane) transparent
        glassPane.setOpaque(false);
        // add empty mouse adapter to block events to other components then JInternalFrame
        glassPane.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){});
        frame.setGlassPane(glassPane);

        final JInternalFrame internal = new JInternalFrame("testFrame", true, true);
        internal.setBounds(20, 20, 240, 200);

        // add listener to hide glassPane when  intenralFrame is closed
        internal.addInternalFrameListener(new InternalFrameListener(){
            public void internalFrameOpened(InternalFrameEvent e) {}
            public void internalFrameClosing(InternalFrameEvent e) {}
            public void internalFrameClosed(InternalFrameEvent e) {
                glassPane.remove(internal);
                glassPane.setVisible(false);
                glassPane.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));
                try {
                    internal.setClosed(true);
                } catch (PropertyVetoException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }           
            }
            public void internalFrameIconified(InternalFrameEvent e) {}
            public void internalFrameDeiconified(InternalFrameEvent e) {}
            public void internalFrameActivated(InternalFrameEvent e) {}
            public void internalFrameDeactivated(InternalFrameEvent e) {}

        });

        // adding exmaple components to frame
        frame.setLayout(new BoxLayout(frame.getContentPane(), BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
        frame.getContentPane().add(new JButton("button 1"));
        // button showing modal JInternalFrame
        JButton activate = new JButton("Show Modal InternalFrame");
        activate.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                glassPane.add(internal);    
                internal.setVisible(true);
                glassPane.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.WAIT_CURSOR));
                glassPane.setVisible(true);
            }       
        });
        frame.getContentPane().add(activate);

        // example menu
        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        JMenu menu = new JMenu("test menu");
        menu.add(new JMenuItem("test"));
        menuBar.add(menu);
        frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
        frame.setSize(800, 600);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) for better help sooner

Comment: have to little bit to describe your idea(s) & reason why you added JInternalFrame to the GlassPane, post an SSCCE

Comment: Example code submitted.

Comment: [crossposted](http://www.coderanch.com/t/341067/GUI/java/Making-JInternalFrame-Modal)

Comment: True, but my question here was earlier :) I really wish to know what swing component generates this behaviour. If anyone has an idea, please share it with me.